# "brown box issue" in chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, jscrollpane

I'm having an issue using the jScrollPane JavaScript plugin in Chrome.

On the link below, you may click anywhere and see "brown boxes" appear around the content:

[**http://colibri-webdesign.de/vstest/plugins.html**](http://colibri-webdesign.de/vstest/plugins.html)

Removing the scrollbar-script makes the problem disappear.

The CSS for styling the scrollbar contains no colorcode any similar to brown.

Since I would really like to use those scrollbars, maybe someone has an idea? help thankfully appreciated! :)

Comment: Have you tried adding border=0 to your divs?

Answer (score 1):

When you initialize your jScroll Plugin, you need to pass in a setting to hide the focus. 
Try this ->

```
$('#myDiv').jScrollPane({
  hideFocus : true
})
```

Here's a [link](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/settings.html) to the rest of the settings I was able to find.
Hope this helps!!!!